# How can I link cpufeatures lib for a native android library?

Tags: android, c++, gcc, android-ndk, linker

I'm trying to link android's cpu_features to a native library.
I'm using android's **gcc** compiler directly as a cross compiler. (**NOT ndk-build**).

I've included the header (**$NDK_PATH/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.h**), but i don't see a prebuilt **libcpufeatures.a** file anywhere under the ndk folder.
How can I build that library? Or where can it be found so i can link it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just include the source file `cpu-features.c` in your project, or build it manually with gcc:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -c cpu-features.c -o cpu-features.o --sysroot=$SYSROOT
arm-linux-androideabi-ar rcs libcpufeatures.a cpu-features.o
```

It shouldn't require any special compiler flags or extra defines, but when linking to it, you may need to add `-ldl` since it uses `dlopen`.

Comment: Yes, but then i'd need to include that in every library that uses that API, which is not the same as linking. I'll have to actually include that .c file in all the builds.

Comment: Then just include `cpu-features.c` as one of the source files in your library (or add `cpu-features.o` into the static library, if that's what you build library into). Since you didn't specify exactly which kind of library you're building, and what sort of build system it's using, it's hard to say exactly what's the most convenient way to do it.